# Select NULL if a calculated column value is negative in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following piece of sql below. The second line (commented out) contains my addition of a check to see **if the calculation returns a negative value in which case it should select NULL**. This case is within a block of multiple other case statements. Since my approach means running the same calculation twice is there a better alternative or more efficient method to selecting NULL if the value of this calculated column is negative, rather than doing two similar calculations?

Thanks

```
CASE 
            WHEN M.ALPHA = 'B' OR T.CT IN (0.001, 0.002) THEN NULL
        --  WHEN ((M.VAL / NULLIF (M.VAL2, 0)) / (NULLIF (T.VAL, 0) / T.VAL2)) < 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE (M.VAL / NULLIF (M.VAL2, 0)) / (NULLIF (T.VAL, 0) / T.VAL2) 
         END As WORLD
```

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (The expression has a return value.)

Comment: A case for `APPLY`.

Comment: Bear in mind that, just because the text of a calculation appears twice in your SQL, that doesn't mean that it's actually going to be computed twice (per row) - if it's deterministic and the optimizer is feeling smart, it may be able to evaluate it once. (Also, the converse is also true - just because you can shift things around to only contain it once, which is good for DRY, it doesn't mean that the system won't evaluate it multiple times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the calculation to a subquery.  For example:

```
select  case
        when CalculatedColumn > 42 then 'Hot'
        when CalculatedColumn < 42 then 'Cold'
        else 'Answer'
        end as Description
from    (
        select  2 * col1 + 3 as CalculatedColumn
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQuery
```

Sometimes it's clearer to define the subquery in a `with` clause:

```
; with  SubQuery as
        (
        select  2 * col1 + 3 as CalculatedColumn
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQuery
select  case
        when CalculatedColumn > 42 then 'Hot'
        when CalculatedColumn < 42 then 'Cold'
        else 'Answer'
        end as Description
from    SubQuery
```